# Silverlight custom mouse cursor without canvas as root?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to use a custom mouse pointer (png image), **without** having a Canvas as the root element? With Canvas as root the mouse works ([like here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2010/03/16/81607.aspx)), but unfortunately I am using several custom controls which don't work well in such setup :(

Thanks!
Palantir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get away from using a Canvas, but that does not mean that you have to abide to how canvas arranges things.

I have created a couple of behaviors that can be useful for you.

The first one is the following:

```
[TypeConstraint(typeof(Canvas))]
public class MouseCursorAction : TargetedTriggerAction<UIElement>
{

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var canvas = AssociatedObject as Canvas;
        if (canvas == null) { return; }
        canvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(canvas_MouseMove);
        canvas.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(canvas_MouseEnter);
        canvas.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(canvas_MouseLeave);
    }

    void canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Target.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    void canvas_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Target.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = sender as Canvas;
        var positionInCanvas = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        Canvas.SetTop(Target, positionInCanvas.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(Target, positionInCanvas.X);
    }
}
```

With this behavior you can convert any UIElement in your mouse cursor. Simply set it to a canvas and select the target that you want the mouse cursor to be.

Now, to solve your layout issues I have created this other behavior:

```
[TypeConstraint(typeof(Canvas))]
public class FillCanvasAction : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var canvas = AssociatedObject as Canvas;
        if (canvas == null) { return; }
        canvas.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(Target_SizeChanged);
    }

    void Target_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = Target;
        if (element == null) { return; }

        var canvas = sender as Canvas;

        element.Width = canvas.ActualWidth;
        element.Height = canvas.ActualHeight;
        Canvas.SetTop(element, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(element, 0);
    }
}
```

This behavior, when attached to a parent canvas, will resize the target FrameworkElement (for example a Grid) to the size of the parent Canvas. This means that you can create your own custom layout inside this FrameworkElement, without having to worry about the way Canvas handles the arrangement.

Then in your XAML you can do something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Cursor="None">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Black">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <local:MouseCursorAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=cursorImage}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger>
                <local:FillCanvasAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=grid}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="White" Width="600" Height="400">
            <!-- Create your layout here -->
        </Grid>
        <Image x:Name="cursorImage" Height="50" Width="50" Source="mouse_cursor.png"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

You can get the complete working code from [here](http://cid-1cd1abfde71f3844.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Answers/ASD.Answer003.zip)

Disclaimer: Strictly speaking this behavior should be implemented using weak event handling to avoid memory leaks; however that implementation is beyond the scope of this answer. You can find more information about weak event handling and whether you will need it or not for your project on this site as well.